# What is a tricoil?

Tags: components

I'm a newbie in these waters so please bear with me and my potentially dumb question.

I have a schematic of a device I want to build that I'm trying to decipher and source the parts for. In the parts list, aside from usual things and codes that are easily google-able and easy to find, I have also the entry "TRICOIL". I've tried google and some forums but no luck. Does anyone know what this part is and what it's called in the language of electronics retailers? I attach a snapshot of the schematic for easier understanding.

Thanks in advance and cheers!

[image: snap from the schematic]

Comment: What is it doing in the circuit?  Would a transformer with two secondaries connected in series make sense?

Comment: With my poor understanding of the circuit, transformer with two secondaries in series does make sense. There are several places in the circuit where this component appears. In two places there's two of them in a circuit with 4 diodes which I understand is a rectifier?
I have a PCB design for this device that I'm having produced and I'm looking for a component that would fit on it according to the parts list...

Comment: i agree with @evildemonic .... google `transformer multiple secondaries`   .... can you post the whole schematic? (or a link)

Comment: Can you post a larger section of the circuit or link to the whole thing?  It would also help to know what the circuit is.

Comment: Reminds me of a push pull MOSFET driver circuit using isolated secondaries.

Comment: Ok, I got help from another source. It's a "trifilar wound toroid". Thanks all for interest and help.
The whole thing is actually a radio transciever, and this transformer appears in several parts of the circuitry.
Thanks again and cheers!

Comment: @MarkoBarovic please either delete this question, or better, yet, post an answer yourself, explaining what this is!

Comment: @evildemonic, a series-connected secondary is nothing more than a center-tapped secondary. (The right-most downward pointing wire is the center tap, in this case.) The figure just looks strange because the transformer windings are conflagurated (that's a tech term /s) to fit within the part's square shape and case pin positions on the schematic diagram. My guess is "TRICOIL" is a brand name or something.

Comment: @JimFischer Thanks and often true, however, there are many transformers where the secondaries are not internally connected and you have the choice of connecting them in series or parallel externally.  In the image above they are in series, which in effect makes a center taped secondary.  Anyway, it turns out the unit in question is a trifilar wound toroid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I got an answer from further reading and other sources. This was a "custom" name for a trifilar wound toroid acting as a transformer in several parts of a RF transciever device.

Thanks all for the insight and helpful comments!

Comment: Please mark this as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Wilco! It has a time limit after which I can accept it since it's my own. In any case I didn't know that was supposed to be done so thanks a lot mate! Love this community!